# Rails 4 customize model attribute name for error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my model I'm using below validation to maker sure user is selected in the UI. It is working fine but it is displaying error message as "users must be given please". I need to print message in the UI as "Representative must be given please".

validates :users, presence: { message: "must be given please" }

I also tried below code in the model but not working, it is still displaying "users must be given please":

```
HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :users => "Representative"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr , options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix by changing the code

validates :users, presence: { scope: :user_id, message: 'Please select Representative.' }